# Change associative array value with PHP and FORM HTML

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, associative-array

I have this exercise for school:

- Write a PHP script that represents a single student's data using an array associative. Each student has a name, age and favorite subject.
- Provide an "EDIT" link within the output page. The link takes you to a page containing a FORM (html) with three inputs (name, age and favorite subject).
  Through the form recover the student's information and insert it into the previously created array.
  Print then the updated array.

My problem is that I don't know how I can update array values from html form. Some advice?
Thank you for your help

Script PHP:

```
  <?php
    $studente = array("nome" => "name", "età" => "age", "materia_preferita" => "subject");
    foreach ($studente as $key => $value) {
        echo $key . " = \n" . $value . "\n" . "<br/>";
    }
    ?>
    </p>
    <p>
    <a href="form.html">Edit</a>
    </p>
```

Page HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="array2.php">
      <input type="text" name="nome[]" placeholder="nome">
      <input type="text" name="età[]" placeholder="età">
      <input type="text" name="materia_preferita[]" placeholder="materia">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Where are you stuck exactly? Have you tried anything? Do you understand how to read POSTed data in a PHP script using `$_POST`? Do you understand how to access array elements in PHP? To help you with this you likely need to add a unique ID to each student entry in the array too, and put that as a hidden field in the "edit" form, so that you know which entry is being edited, and you can then find that item in the array and set new values for it.

Comment: Also why do you have square-bracket syntax in the form (e.g. `name="nome[]"`)? That's only if you need to enter multiple values for the same field, which is not the case here.

Comment: Oh and `<a href="form.html">Edit</a>` isn't sufficient - it doesn't indicate to the receiving script which array element is being edited. It would need to point to a PHP script which can a) receive a URL parameter via $_GET (e.g. <a href="edit.php?id=1">Edit</a>` as the link and then `$id = $_GET["id"];` in the edit.php), and use that  to pre-populate the form with the details of the student being edited.

Comment: (It would need to retrieve them  from the array using the ID, so you'll need the array details shared in the edit file too - I suggest putting the array code in a separate file you can `include` into all the others, so it's always available but you don't have to write the same code 3 times).

Comment: Also remember that web applications are stateless - if you make any updates to the array, don't expect them to persist beyond the request in which the updated data was posted. If you want such a feature, you'll need to introduce persistent storage such as serialising the array data to a file, or storing in a database, and then retrieving it again at the start of the next run. It wasn't clear what the scope of your exercise was and whether it included that requirement or not.

Comment: Hi, sorry. We just begin with PHP and we did only array, conditional and basic stuff of PHP. This is an "advance" exercise that we have to do with the things we learned, so I don't know how to do it. Because they didn't say anything about to do it, no advice.

Comment: Strange...you should maybe talk to the tutor in case you missed some important points from the class. Or maybe the idea is that you should try to some tutorials or something and research it yourself as much as possible - that's an important skill for a programmer too! It's fine to ask here, but don't expect a whole solution on a plate...that's not what Stackoveflow is about, and it wouldn't help your learning process either. You should identify a more specific aspect of the task where you are struggling to take the next step, and make that the main subject of your question. See also [ask]

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I think I'll try to talk with the teacher, because maybe I missed something as you told